# Large screen scale genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm facing a very annoying bug with Oracle Virtual Machine and GenyMotion.

Yesterday, this strange scale in the amulator started to happen.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it? In my desktop works just fine.